# How to set height of extrusion in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm using the following code to make a trapezoid shape. I need to extrude this geometry to a specific height (2800), but I can't seem to figure out where to set the height parameter. Any ideas?

```
//Walls

var wallPoints = [[0,0,0],
                  [0,1000,0],
                  [-100,1100,0],
                  [-100,-100,0],
                  [0,0,0]];

var Vector3WallPoints = [];

for (var i=0;i<wallPoints.length;i++)
{ 
Vector3WallPoints.push(new THREE.Vector3(wallPoints[i][0],wallPoints[i][1],wallPoints[i][2]));
}

var wallShape = new THREE.Shape( Vector3WallPoints );

var extrusionSettings = {
    amount: 1000,
    //size: 300, height: 400, curveSegments: 3,
    //bevelThickness: 10, bevelSize: 20, bevelEnabled: false,
    material: 0, extrudeMaterial: 1, amount: 100,
    };

    var wallGeometry = new THREE.ExtrudeGeometry( wallShape, extrusionSettings );                           

    var materialFront = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
    var materialSide = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0xff8800 } );
    var materialArray = [ materialFront, materialSide ];
    var wallMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(materialArray);

    var walls = new THREE.Mesh( wallGeometry, wallMaterial );

    scene.add(walls);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting `amount` twice in the same object. If you are setting the first one, the other one is overriding it. Remove one of those and it should do what you expect.

```
var extrusionSettings = {
    amount: 1000,
    material: 0, extrudeMaterial: 1, amount: 100, // <-- whoops
};
```

Assuming you are using the THREE.js api properly here, I'm not 100% of that myself.